# Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе числа через консоль для типа double проверялся диапазон (от -1.0 до 1.0)

Tags: c#, циклы, консоль

Если диапазон не верный, то заново начинать цикл.
Я через do...while пытался реализовать данную фичу.
                     Код:

```
double x;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите значение x:");
    Console.WriteLine("(В диапазоне от -1.00 до 1.00.)");
} while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double x;
bool result;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите значение x:");
    Console.WriteLine("(В диапазоне от -1.00 до 1.00.)");
    result = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);

} while (!result || x <= -1.0 || x >= 1.0);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, он решил мою проблему. У меня есть еще один вопрос касаемо этой темы. Почему при вводе через консоль дробные числа принимаются только через запятую, а точка не интерпретируется консолью С#, как способ разделения целой и дробной части?

Comment: @Diareich Это зависит от настроек локали в системе, а конкретно десятичного разделителя. В нашей локали десятичный разделитель - запятая, а в английской обычно точка. Можно сделать топорный способ: заменять во вводимой строке точку на запятую и потом ее обрабатывать.

Comment: @Diareich - это вполне можно было задать отдельным вопросом. Как уже отметил Геннадий, это зависит от настроек ОС. В коде можно либо использовать другую перегрузку `TryParse` - в ней можно указать желаемую культуру, либо задавать культуру в `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.